# AWS CloudWatch metrics: How are Network metrics calculated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-cloudwatch

How does AWS calculates the network in and network out metrics?

I have two instances, one running application and another running database. I want to know the network traffic between these two instances. What is the best way to get that?

Answer (score 0):

To discover traffic between two specific locations, you would need to activate [VPC Flow Logs - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html):

> VPC Flow Logs is a feature that enables you to capture information about the IP traffic going to and from network interfaces in your VPC. Flow log data can be published to Amazon CloudWatch Logs or Amazon S3. After you've created a flow log, you can retrieve and view its data in the chosen destination.

VPC Flow Logs can be activated on the whole VPC, a subnet, or a specific Elastic Network Interface ENI). The Flow Log will show information *about* each packet, but not the *contents* of the packet.

You would need to use a tool to then gather and aggregate information from the logs, such as: [Querying Amazon VPC Flow Logs - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/vpc-flow-logs.html)